# Recovering lost cronjob rules

Tags: centos7, cron

I wanted to export my cronjobs to a file. So, I did this.

```
crontab -e > /export/location/file.txt
```

This returned a message:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
```

and the terminal became unresponsive. I killed it, and started it again. Typed

```
crontab -l > /export/location/file.txt
```

which gave back an empty file.

Checked `/var/spool/cron/` and the file `root` was empty. Same thing with `crontab -l` - no cronjobs are there.

I'm guessing I messed things up with the first command. Is there a way to recover what was there, without manually adding everything back? Are there any automatic backups (by default)?

My server OS is CentOs 7.

Comment: Interesting. Can't reproduce this on Ubuntu. Crontab -e and kill -9 or normal kill does not erase the crontab. Anyway, maybe you can pluck the commands from the syslog.

Comment: @Gerrit If it's of any importance, my SSH connection (Windows machine to remote CentOS server) was via BitVise, and the terminal was started from there. Regarding the second suggestion, I came to the same conclusion myself, and ended up doing that.

Comment: crontab -e is already a file in /var/spool/cron, just copy it.

Comment: @Peleion Nope, I only see two files there - apache and root. The first one is a file with comments, and the root is empty (this is where my rules were).

Comment: That's what I meant - copy the file _before_ you delete it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not unless you've got backups.